# Multiple Force Close is coming in my application

Tags: android

In my application when anywhere one force close is coming after that a sequence of force close starts.When i click on "Ok" for first force close then second force close comes . This is coming in 4-5 times.
This is only a situation where multiple force close comes at same time.I search at various places , but cant find the solution of this problem.I just want to know its reason.Code and logcat is changes every time.Anywhere in my app when force close starts its comes 4-5 times one after one.The reason of Force close is different in each time.
Exception is different too. but result is always a sequence of force close.
Where can be problem in this . Kindly suggest me.

Comment: "M not posting any code for this or any logcat.Where can be problem in this" - We are not magician..'

Comment: People if you read my answer you will see that the situation really is as general as he describes. Maybe he does not deserve so many negations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is that if an Activity throws an exception, Android tries to reload your previous Activity in the stack with the current state. However, it seems that it also throws an exception and so on several levels. You just need to ensure in such situations that you will not propagate the errors along the Activity stack.

Comment: thax boris, i just want to know the reason behind it nothing else.sure i will give more to write my next question.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say you deserved all the minuses, but however. You need to verify that neither of your activities will break if you return with an error from the next activity. If you will never need to support going back to previous activity you can just call `finish()` immediately after the `callActivityForResult()` - this will remove the calling Activity from the activity stack and it will not throw exception.

Comment: My application is web based , if i will finish the activity . I have to again send the request to server and fetch all the json records every time.when i dont use Finish() then its stores my previous activity.M showing data and images in each activity. So, it will take time again for same activity.

Comment: Ok I see. this is usually the case. Then you need to store somewhere the fetched data (I propose database) and refetch it from there every time you restart the activity.

Comment: This approach will be good with text data. I have lots of Images. if i will download or store all images ,it also increase user's data usages(3G is costly) and memory issues. So, m confusing which approach i sud to follow.

Comment: You will need to pay something for the luxury of not crashing. Downloading every time is not an option. I recommend you to store the images locally (which I am sure you already do in order to display) and just record their location in a database.

Comment: +1 , thanks for ur valueable time and suggestions :)